# Scanning Log Lines for Specific Destination IP Addresses and Extracting fields

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I am reaching out to seek your expertise and assistance with a task I'm currently working on. I have a text file containing log lines, and I need to scan these lines for specific destination IP addresses and extract certain fields from them.

The IPs I want to scan the lines for are around 50, so I need to feed the script these 50 IP addresses as IP1, IP2, and so on.

The field for destination IP is dst_ip in the log below and the same line has protocol, and dst_port fields.

And then extract the fields highlighted below: dst_ip, protocol, and dst_port

I would prefer if this can be done in CMD with a batch file on windows, as my experience with python scripting and so on is very beginner level, but I am open to try out suggestions.

Here's a log snippet:

```
device="SFW" date=2023-06-21 time=09:41:51 timezone="AEST" device_name="XG310" device_id=C30055Q2CVGH6FC log_id=010202601001 log_type="Firewall" log_component="Invalid Traffic" log_subtype="Denied" status="Deny" priority=Information duration=0 fw_rule_id=0 policy_type=0 user_name="" user_gp="" iap=0 ips_policy_id=0 appfilter_policy_id=0 application="" application_risk=0 application_technology="" application_category="" in_interface="Port4" out_interface="" src_mac=34:0a:98:30:4b:91 src_ip=10.1.2.3 src_country_code= dst_ip=10.3.2.1 dst_country_code= protocol="TCP" src_port=80 dst_port=1433 sent_pkts=0  recv_pkts=0 sent_bytes=0 recv_bytes=0 tran_src_ip= tran_src_port=0 tran_dst_ip= tran_dst_port=0 srczonetype="" srczone="" dstzonetype="" dstzone="" dir_disp="" connid="" vconnid="" hb_health="No Heartbeat" message="Could not associate packet to any connection." appresolvedby="Signature" app_is_cloud=0
```

I have multiple log lines like these and every line should be parsed individually and match those fields based on the IP I have added to be searched. The log file is pretty huge up to 1GB

I tried various ways in notepad++ but could not meet these requirements, I believe this can be done much fasted in a batch script or python script.

Comment: @Compo not sure about the question, I have multiple log lines like these and every line should be parsed individually and match those fields based on the IP I have added to be searched. The log file is pretty huge up to 1gb.

Comment: Please delete your above comment wannabemssp, I have added the information it contains to the question area.

Comment: Please clarify that the all log lines, containing the IP addresses you're searching for, do not contain any other information, (than that you've submitted), and that the key pairs, (values and data), are always logged in the same order on each line, as your submission too.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory,
rem filenames and output filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
:: Logfile
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q76538278.txt"
:: File of IPs
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q76538278_2.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

:: First create a list of "dst_ip=..." for each required IP
SET "iplist="
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename2%") DO SET "iplist=!iplist![%%e]"
SET "iplist=%iplist:[= /c:" dst_ip=%"
SET "iplist=%iplist:]= "%"
:: Now have `iplist` in the form [ /c:"dst_ip=IP1" ]*

:: Read the log file and filter on required IPs

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('findstr /L %iplist% "%filename1%"') DO (
 SET "line=%%e"
 SET "line=!line:* dst_ip=!"
 FOR /f %%o IN ("!line:~1!") DO SET "DSTIP=%%o"
 SET "line=!line:* protocol=!"
 FOR /f %%o IN ("!line:~1!") DO SET "PROTOCOL=%%~o"
 SET "line=!line:* dst_port=!"
 FOR /f %%o IN ("!line:~1!") DO SET "DSTPORT=%%o"
 ECHO !DSTIP! !PROTOCOL! !DSTPORT!
)

GOTO :eof
```

I have my doubts whether this will cope with the filesizes you've mentioned. It should work with smaller files, so just split your data files into many smaller files.

The first step is to construct a list of the form `/c:" dst_ip=IP1 "`  for all of the IPs. This can be used by `findstr` to locate all of the records of interest.

For each record of interest, delete from the line all characters up to the string of interest, and use a `for /f` to split off the first token in the rest of the line.

Show the results...

Comment: Please be aware wannabemssp, that the above idea is based upon the idea that the key pairs, (values and data), are always logged in the same order on each line, as your submission. I've already asked about this, and you've not clarified, so this answer was constructed to assume such.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest and fastest way to solve this problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the list of around 50 destination IP's to search for
set "ipList= 10.3.2.1 10.4.2.1 10.5.2.1 10.6.2.1 "
rem If the list of IP's is feed to the script from a text file, a very simple change is needed

rem Process the lines of input file that contains anyone of search IP
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /L "%ipList%" test.txt') do (
   set "line=%%a"

   rem Extract all fields from current line
   call :extractFields > NUL 2>&1

   rem If the current dst_ip appears in the ipList
   for %%d in (!dst_ip!) do if "!iplist: %%d =!" neq "%iplist%" (

      rem Show required fields
      echo dst_ip=!dst_ip!  protocol=!protocol!  dst_port=!dst_port!

   )

)
goto :EOF


:extractFields
set "%line: =" & set "%"
exit /B
```

This code works with *any fields* in the file, excepting fields that may have spaces, like `log_component`. If you also want to process a field of this type, a small modification in the code is required.